# Target individual div using jQuery $this

Tags: jquery, html, css

Any help greatly appreciated, basically I need the below (js fiddle link) to work when you hover over the individual div.

As you can see it is been applied to all divs. I have tried using $this but i'm clearly coding it wrong.

**jQuery**

```
$('.exampleholder').hover(function() {
$(this).slideDown();
});

$('.flyout').mouseout(function() {
window.isoverdiv = false;
setTimeout(function() {
if (!window.isoverdiv) {
$('.flyout').slideUp();
}
}, 1000);
});
$('.flyout').mouseover(function() {
window.isoverdiv = true;
});
```

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bowerslive/hgdwK/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle is empty. Please add your HTML/jQuery code and save the jsFiddle.

Comment: `slideDown()` is way to `show()` a hidden element. So it looks to me like your `.hover()` function will never get called, since you will never hover over a hidden element...

Comment: Js Fiddle link now updated, many thanks

Comment: Thanks, that helped understand the issue a lot better ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to limit the `slidedown()` to only the `next()` `.flyout` element.

```
$('.exampleholder').hover(function() {
  $(this).next('.flyout').slideDown();
});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/3nvuR/).

Comment: Thank you so much, really appreciated, I will stick to HTML and CSS from now on ;)

Comment: Once you spend some time playing with jQuery selectors you'll get the hang of it. So don't give up too easily. It's a great skill to have and will help you learn more general javascript in the process.

Comment: What would you suggest, books, tutorials?

Comment: Everyone learns differently so go with whatever works for you. Personally I like to start writing code and see where it leads me. One option, find a question on stackoverflow and try to solve it. If you stuck, go to the answers for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.flyout').mouseout(function() {

    window.isoverdiv = false;
    var $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        if ( ! window.isoverdiv ) {
            $this.slideUp();
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```